# Insert or update multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to implement hashtags functionality with NodeJS and MongoDB support, so that I can also count the uses. Whenever a user adds hashtags to a page, I want to push or update them in the database. Each hastag looks like this:

```
{_id:<auto>, name:'hashtag_name', uses: 0}
```

The problem I'm facing is that the user can add new tags as well, so when he clicks 'done', I have to increment the 'uses' field for the existing tags, and add the new ones. The trick is how to do this with only one Mongo instruction? So far I thought of 2 possible ways of achieving this, but I'm not particularly happy with either:

**Option 1**

I have a service which fetches the existing tags from the db before the user starts to write a new article. Based on this, I can detect which tags are new, and run 2 queries: one which will add the new tags, and another which will update the existing one

**Option 2**

I will send the list of tags to the server, and there I will run a find() for every tag; if I found one, I'll update, if not, I'll create it.

**Option 3** (without solution for now)

Best option would be to run a query which takes an array of tag names, do a $inc operation for the existing ones, and add the missing ones.

**The question**

Is there a better solution? Can I achieve the end result from option #3?

Comment: what is your current version of mongodb, 3.x ?

Comment: yes, 3.x. forgot to mention, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this, all of them will be executed in one batch, this is only an snippet idea how to do it:

```
var db = new Db('DBName', new Server('localhost', 27017));
    // Establish connection to db
    db.open(function(err, db) {
    // Get the collection
    var col = db.collection('myCollection');

    var batch = col.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    for (var tag in hashTagList){
      // Add all tags to be executed (inserted or updated) 
      batch.find({_id:tag.id}).upsert().updateOne({$inc: {uses:1}});
    }

    batch.execute(function(err, result) {
      db.close();
    });
  });
```

Comment: seems to work from console, now the trouble is it doesn't work from mongoskin :D. Anyway, it's the answer to the original question..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [Bulk method](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk/) offered by Mongodb since version 2.6. In the same you could perform insertion operations when the tag is new and the counter update when it already exists.

Comment: "The URL you requested does not exist or has been removed."
I saw an example of Bulk but not sure how to adapt it to my current situation. This will happen programatically, it's not something i need to do from console.

Comment: It's correct what you say, the URL was wrong, I fixed it. Anyway, msoliman's answer is correct and complete.
Regards.