# Bulk operations in Mongoskin

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

There are several questions on how to run bulk operations with mongoskin, but none of the answers provied are still working. The need for bulk operations is described in a previous question, here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46911914/insert-or-update-multiple-documents-in-mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631772/how-to-use-unordered-bulk-inserting-with-mongoskin)

The only answer which seemed valid is the one from here: [How to use unordered bulk inserting with Mongoskin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631772/how-to-use-unordered-bulk-inserting-with-mongoskin)

but looking at the mongoskin code, the collection() is not accepting a callback anymore. and running bulk.execute() returns `"execute is not a method"`

Is anyone using mongoskin, and has a solution for this?

Comment: The code works perfectly, as both the original author and having just tested it. Considering that mongoskin is generally a "pass through" to the native driver then since the native driver supports a callback on `collection()` then so does mongoskin. Documented for [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin#dbcollection-callback) and the [native driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collection).

Comment: The only thing I would not really recommend is connecting with anything other than `MongoClient` since other conection method are deprecated and soon to be removed from the MongoDB API. And considering this is basically a "full bypass of all wrapping function"  included in `mongoskin`, then it kind of makes the whole driver redundant. So you really may as well simply use the [native driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) instead. And honestly you "should". There is even `Promise` support built in there now.

Comment: Thank you @NeilLunn, I will put that on my todo list. Regarding the callback, I put a log as the only instruction in my callback, and it never gets displayed. There was another user with the same issue, the callback for 'collection' was never called, and looking at the collection code in the mongoskin files, the part where the callback was used is commented out, with a message: "// mongodb now support collection without callback" 
https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin/blob/master/lib/db.js  - line 50.